# Build function from grammar OCaml

Tags: ocaml, context-free-grammar

I'm trying to build a parser from a generic grammar 
But first I'm asked to change the grammar from this (A is the start symbol):

```
(A,[(A,[C;B;C]);
    (A,[C]);
    (B,[A]);
    (C,[B])])
```

To something that looks like this:

```
   (A,
   function
   | A -> [[C;B;C];[C]]
   | B -> [[C]]
   | C -> [[B]])
```

how do I generate a pattern matcher from the information in the list? 
A pattern matcher (function | pattern | ... | pattern) is defined by the programmer, how to create one on the fly with information from a list that has this structure (A,[[C;B;C];[C]])::rest  ?

If you want to look a bigger grammar that makes more sense look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584247/parsing-grammars-using-ocaml).

Comment: (I can't find a question here.)

Comment: I'm wondering how to generate that data structure given a list that looks like this (A,[[C;B;C];[C]])::rest

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [ocamllex](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual026.html) and [menhir](http://gallium.inria.fr/~fpottier/menhir/) which are tools designed for lexing and parsing.

Comment: Thanks, I knew about those tools, but they aren't what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I might understand your question. A data structure starting with function is a function! In OCaml, functions are first class objects, and you can create new ones, keep them in data structures, and so on. To keep things pure, you can't access the textual representation of a function (as you can in some languages), but you can still combine functions in useful ways.

Here's a tiny example. The function `maketest` takes a value `k` and returns a function that tests for `k`.

```
# let maketest k = fun x -> x = k;;
val maketest : 'a -> 'a -> bool = <fun>
# let t8 = maketest 8;;
val t8 : int -> bool = <fun>
# t8 3;;
- : bool = false
# t8 8;;
- : bool = true
```

The function `union` takes two test functions (like those generated by `maketest`) and returns a function that tests for the union of the two sets of values:

```
# let union f g = fun x -> f x || g x;;
val union : ('a -> bool) -> ('a -> bool) -> 'a -> bool = <fun>
# let t812 = union t8 (maketest 12);;
val t812 : int -> bool = <fun>
# t812 8;;
- : bool = true
# t812 12;;
- : bool = true
# t812 14;;
- : bool = false
#
```

The function `sequence` takes two test functions (like those generated by `maketest`) and tests for a list beginning with ints that match the two functions in turn.

```
# let sequence f g = function
  | []|[_] -> false
  | a :: b :: _ -> f a && g b;;
val sequence : ('a -> bool) -> ('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> bool = <fun>
# sequence (maketest 1) (maketest 4) [1;4;7];;
- : bool = true
# sequence (maketest 1) (maketest 4) [1;8;7];;
- : bool = false
#
```

I'm not completely sure, but I think you're being asked to create functions somewhat like these for the components of your grammar. To make a parser from functions like this you'll need to track your progress through the input stream. The usual way would be to have the parsing functions return the remaining (unparsed) stream.

Comment: I see your point. I need a bit more help. I rephrased the question.

Comment: Assuming you read the new question... I kind of see how I could get what I want with (fun x -> f x ||...), but it needs to be comparable to (function | .. | ..). I don't think you can compare it with (=) to your approach.